# Cypress failed to start Windows

Tags: cypress

I have installed Cypress on my Windows 10 machine.
From my project folder in VSCode Terminal window I first ran npm init -y
I then run the following command npm install cypress --force
I then run the command npx cypress open I get the following error

```
PS C:\Projects\Cypress Projects\QACypressDemo> npm install cypress --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

added 219 packages, and audited 220 packages in 37s

16 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Projects\Cypress Projects\QACypressDemo> npx cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 7.3.0

  ×  Verifying Cypress can run C:\Users\Usera\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.3.0\Cypress
    → Cypress Version: 7.3.0
Cypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.

----------

#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Failed to deserialize the V8 snapshot blob. This can mean that the snapshot blob file is corrupted or missing.
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000BA300FEE30
1: 00007FF6C6C8BCCF node::OnFatalError+69935
2: 00007FF6C1AFE6CA Ordinal0+59082
3: 00007FF6C20ACEC8 v8::Isolate::Initialize+744
4: 00007FF6C2B6D48F v8::Isolate::AddMessageListenerWithErrorLevel+1039
5: 00007FF6C56D7583 std::__1::vector<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo,std::__1::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo> >::max_size+857811
6: 00007FF6C56CF89B std::__1::vector<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo,std::__1::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo> >::max_size+825835
7: 00007FF6C60DA382 v8_inspector::protocol::Binary::operator=+2434098
8: 00007FF6C60DDC29 v8_inspector::protocol::Binary::operator=+2448601
9: 00007FF6C60D9E12 v8_inspector::protocol::Binary::operator=+2432706
10: 00007FF6C5DFB2D0 v8::ExtensionConfiguration::ExtensionConfiguration+2964624
11: 00007FF6C5DFAEEA v8::ExtensionConfiguration::ExtensionConfiguration+2963626
12: 00007FF6C5DF9E57 v8::ExtensionConfiguration::ExtensionConfiguration+2959383
13: 00007FF6C5DFA17D v8::ExtensionConfiguration::ExtensionConfiguration+2960189
14: 00007FF6C5603167 uv_sleep+2434663
15: 00007FF6C803FF02 uv_random+10012786
16: 00007FFFCF1937E4 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
17: 00007FFFD10ECB81 RtlUserThreadStart+33

----------

Platform: win32 (10.0.16299)
Cypress Version: 7.3.0
```

I tried deleting the Cypress folder from and run the install command again.  Cypress still fails to run
C:\Users\Usera\AppData\Local\cypress

Not sure why Cypress won't run, the test runner won't open.  Any ideas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I`ve had such problems when an installation was interrupted mid-way. You can [clear the cache](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-cache-command) and install it again. I used the following sequence:

```
cypress cache clear
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

Comment: 'npx cypress cache clear'

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` and `npx cypress` run the binaries in two different locations. If you want to use the binary you installed into the directory, you need to run the binary found in the node module folder. On Windows, if you run `./node_modules/.bin/cypress` that should start up the version in your node modules folder.